# IE and :first-of-type

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I'm a beginner, so if u know other solution tell me ;)
I want to make menu on my website look like this:

```
link / link / link / link / link
```

Menu is in  so here's what I've made:

```
li:before {
    content: "/";
}

li:first-of-type {
    color: #FFF; /* I've made first "/" same color as background, so we don't see it */
}
```

There are some padding tags so it looks nice, but I want to make it simple to read for You.

In most browsers it looks fine, but of course older Internet Explorer doesn't support :first-of-type tag. How can I work it out, so the user don't see just the first slash?

Answer (score 15):

```
li:first-child:before {
    content: '';
}
```

The `:first-child` pseudo class is supported by IE7 and later.

Note that IE7 supports `:first-child` ([with some caveats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17)), but not until IE9 did it support its friend `:last-child`.

Also, to hide content added with `content` property, don't change the color to match the background color, as that is what I would call an *ugly hack*.

Instead, set its `content` to an empty string, like in the example above.

Comment: +1 ... because `:first-child` is part of CSS2 while `:first-of-type` and `:last-child` are part of CSS3.

Comment: So fast, so simple... And I couldn't find it on the internet ;) Thank you very much

Comment: @smogg: *now 't iz on the internets*

Comment: @Tomalak What are you referring to there? I made so many ninja edits, now I am not sure :P

Comment: @alex: Your second paragraph of text. :) [Though Boltclock since pointed out that it's really CSS's fault.]